# asp.net mvc nested object validation message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. I need to show all messages for
   nested child object of parent. Here
   is model simplfied

   ```
    class Parent
    {
       Child SomeChild
    }

    class Child: IValidatableObject
    {
      [Required]
       string Address;
      [Required]
       string City
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(parent => parent.SomeChild)
   ```

   It doesn't works. Of course

   ```
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(parent =>parent.SomeChild.Address)
   ```

   works but
   in this case I should do this for
   every property. Or do reflection...
   Also I am not sure about
   `IValidatableObject` interface. How to
   extract its message?
2. 1st was simplified problem. Lets
   complicate it. Lets say that Child
   object is passed in Partial view
   where it is rendered. Partial view
   model includes also other properties
   for combo boxes to transfer them to
   partial view. They are filled in
   parent controller

   ```
   @Html.Partial("ChildPartial", new ChildPartialModel(Model.SomeChild,SelectList, SelectListN)
   ```

How I could do show error message in such partial?

**UPDATE** second issue resolved. In partial path in ValidationMessageFor should be like in parent.
So if in parent we has Model.Data.Child but in partial we has Model.Child we should use Model.Data,Child.
As lambdas are not possible in this case I have used ValidationMessage with text string